# Python code doesn't execute. exiting code 0

Tags: python, tkinter

i am on a project about square puzzle but my program is not responding to execution call.its about a simple square puzzle game with highest score feature. i have written this code but i cant run it. exiting with code 0 but did not showing anything on the screen

here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import os
import time
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Parça Parça")
author_label = tk.Label(window, text="xxx", font=("Arial", 10))
author_label.pack(side="bottom", pady=10)
title_label = tk.Label(window, text="Parça Parça", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
title_label.pack(side="top", pady=10)
name_label = tk.Label(window, text="Adınızı girin:")
name_label.pack()
name_entry = tk.Entry(window)
name_entry.pack()
load_button = tk.Button(window, text="Resim Yükle")
load_button.pack()
def select_image():
    file_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if file_path:
        image = image.open(file_path)
        image = image.resize((400, 400))
        image_list = []
        for i in range(0, 400, 100):
            for j in range(0, 400, 100):
                piece = image.crop((i, j, i+100, j+100))
                image_list.append(piece)
        random.shuffle(image_list)
        grid = [image_list[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(image_list), 4)]
        node_grid = []
        for i in range(4):
            row = []
            for j in range(4):
                piece = grid[i][j]
                node = Node(piece, i, j)
                row.append(node)
            node_grid.append(row)
        game_start(node_grid)
load_button.config(command=select_image)
class Node:
    def __init__(self, piece, row, col):
        self.piece = piece
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.button = None
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

def create_linked_list(grid):
    head = None
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            node = grid[i][j]
            if not head:
                head = node
            else:
                curr = head
                while curr.next:
                    curr = curr.next
                curr.next = node
                node.prev = curr
    return head
def shuffle_pieces():
    global puzzle_pieces
    random.shuffle(puzzle_pieces)
    for row in range(4):
        for col in range(4):
            button = puzzle_pieces[row * 4 + col][0]
            button.grid(row=row+1, column=col)

def move_piece(button):
    global moves, score
    empty_row, empty_col = find_empty_position()
    button_row, button_col = get_position(button)
    if empty_row == button_row and abs(empty_col - button_col) == 1 or \
       empty_col == button_col and abs(empty_row - button_row) == 1:
        swap_buttons(button, empty_row, empty_col, button_row, button_col)
        moves += 1
        score += 5
        score_label.config(text="Score: " + str(score))
        check_solution()
def check_pieces():
    global correct_pieces
    correct_pieces = 0
    for piece in pieces:
        if piece.current_row == piece.final_row and piece.current_col == piece.final_col:
            correct_pieces += 1
    if correct_pieces == num_pieces:
        messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations", "You have completed the puzzle!")

score = 0

def update_score(correct_move):
    global score
    if correct_move:
        score += 5
    else:
        score -= 10
    score_label.config(text=f"Score: {score}")

# with open('enyuksekskor.txt', 'a') as f:
#     f.write(f"{kullanici_adi}: Hamle sayisi: {hamle_sayisi}, Puan: {puan}\n")

# def en_yuksek_skorlari_goster():
#     skorlar = []
#     with open('enyuksekskor.txt', 'r') as f:
#         for line in f:
#             skorlar.append(line.strip())

#     # skorları puanlarına göre sırala
#     skorlar.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(':')[-1].strip().split()[-1]), reverse=True)

#     # en yüksek 10 skoru göster
#     skorlar = skorlar[:10]
#     skor_text = "\n".join(skorlar)
#     skor_label.config(text=skor_text)
```

and when i run the program terminal output is PS C:\Users\xxx> & C:/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx.py

Comment: Aren't you missing a `window.mainloop()` at the end of your code?

Comment: thank you... it was so simple

Comment: An exit code of 0 indicates _success_, not failure. Your code _is_ executing, and it's completing as written. It just isn't doing what you want it to do due to the logic error noted in a comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `mainloop()` on your instance of `Tk()` to start the GUI event loop (and launch the GUI). Add this to the bottom of your script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.mainloop()
```